# What are the expected value for the Docusign API "Accounts: getBillingCharges"

Tags: docusignapi

I am referring to an [getBillingCharges](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/accounts/accounts/getbillingcharges/) API to get details of Envelopes.
Below is the Envelope part of this API for my Business Pro account.

```json
{
   "chargeName": "envelopes",
   "chargeType": "usage",
   "chargeUnitOfMeasure": "envelopes",
   "allowedQuantity": "unlimited",
   "usedQuantity": "0",
   "includedQuantity": "10",
   "firstEffectiveDate": "2021-05-01T07:00:00.0000000Z",
   "lastEffectiveDate": "2021-06-01T07:00:00.0000000Z",
   "blocked": "false",
   "prices": [
     {
       "unitPrice": "$0.00",
       "beginQuantity": "1",
       "endQuantity": "10"
     },
     {
       "unitPrice": "$0.00",
       "beginQuantity": "11",
       "endQuantity": "unlimited"
     }
   ],
   "discounts": [
     {
       "endQuantity": "unlimited",
       "beginQuantity": "1",
       "discount": "$0.00"
     }
   ]
 }
```

Can someone help me in getting answer to some of the questions I have below?

1. Will the *usedQuantity* includes the count of bulk send Envelopes.
2. If I consume envelopes more than *includedQuantity* will the *usedQuantity* contains the count of all consumed envelopes i.e.value more than 10 in my case.
3. What will be the *firstEffectiveDate* and *lastEffectiveDate* in case of Annual billing
4. Will the *usedQuantity* change every month.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Will the usedQuantity includes the count of bulk send Envelopes.
   No, Envelopes and bulk_recipient_envelopes, they're two different charge names. When user sends envelopes, it counts under usedQuantity of envelopes charge name and when user sends bulk envelopes, it counts under usedQuantity of bulk_recipient_envelopes charge name.
2. If I consume envelopes more than includedQuantity will the usedQuantity contains the count of all consumed envelopes i.e.value more than 10 in my case.
   Yes, it contains all usedQuantity (even if it's more that includedQuantity)
   We dont have any limits in the product
3. What will be the firstEffectiveDate and lastEffectiveDate in case of Annual billing
   : Billing Start date and end date
4. Will the usedQuantity change every month.
   Our understanding is yes